# Activar y desactivar clases en navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código en donde la clase "is-expanded" en li (Catalogo) y su hijo con clase  "active" (Pantalones), esas dos clases en un navbar le dan un efecto de marcado y activo tanto al padre como al hijo, como podría agregar y quitar a la vez estas clases mediante js nativo o jquery dando click.

```html
<ul class="app-menu">
  <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="#"><i class="app-menu__icon fa fa-dashboard"></i><span
        class="app-menu__label">Inicio</span></a></li>
  <li class="treeview is-expanded"><a class="app-menu__item" href="#" data-toggle="treeview"><i
        class="app-menu__icon fa fa-laptop"></i><span class="app-menu__label">Catalogo</span><i
        class="treeview-indicator fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><a class="treeview-item active" href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>Pantalones</a></li>
      <li><a class="treeview-item" href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>Chompa</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview"><a class="app-menu__item" href="#" data-toggle="treeview"><i
        class="app-menu__icon fa fa-edit"></i><span class="app-menu__label">Especialidad</span><i
        class="treeview-indicator fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><a class="treeview-item" href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>Informes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ¿Haz intentado algo al respecto?

Comment: Si con classList.add, classList.remove y toggleClass pero no logro hacer que funcione.

Comment: Agrega eso por favor, es un punto de partida

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elementos = document.querySelectorAll('li')
    const link = document.querySelectorAll('li a')

    link.forEach((t) => {
        t.addEventListener('click', () => {
            resetL()
            t.classList.add('active')
            
        })
    })
    const resetL = () => {
        link.forEach(y => y.classList.remove('active'))
    }

    elementos.forEach((elemento) => {
        elemento.addEventListener('click', () => {
            reset()
            elemento.classList.add('is-expanded')
            
        })
    })

    const reset = () => {
        elementos.forEach(x => x.classList.remove('is-expanded'))
    }
```

```css
 .is-expanded {
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        
        .active {
            background-color: rgb(108, 116, 108);
        }
```

```html
<ul id="list" class="app-menu">
        <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="#"><i class="app-menu__icon fa fa-dashboard"></i><span
              class="app-menu__label">Inicio</span></a></li>
        <li class="treeview "><a class="app-menu__item" href="#" data-toggle="treeview"><i
              class="app-menu__icon fa fa-laptop"></i><span class="app-menu__label">Catalogo</span><i
              class="treeview-indicator fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a class="treeview-item " href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>Pantalones</a></li>
                <li><a class="treeview-item" href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>Chompa</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview"><a class="app-menu__item" href="#" data-toggle="treeview"><i
              class="app-menu__icon fa fa-edit"></i><span class="app-menu__label">Especialidad</span><i
              class="treeview-indicator fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a class="treeview-item" href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>Informes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

hola:
no entendi muy bien como lo necesitas, pero aqui esta mi aportaion, al seleccionar un elemento li pone la clase: is-expanded  al seleccionar otro elemento, se la quita al todos los que no esten seleccionados, y la clase active del elemento a se añade cuando seleccionas el elemento, espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias por responder, coloque este código debajo de todos mis script y debajo de la librería jQuery pero no me funciona

Comment: olvide mencionar que html tambien fue modificado, se eliminaron todas las clases 'is-expanded'  y 'active', para que la funcion las coloque al hacer click, no necesitas llamar las funciones con onClick desde html, al cargar el archivo ya estan listas para ejecutarse